# Get form_key with javascript in Magento 2.0?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I would like to create a custom login page from outside Magento. To do so I need to get the form_key.

How can I get the current form_key using javascript and/or PHP from outside Magento?

**Notes:**

I am willing to add a PHP file inside Magento to generate the for_key (but I don't know what to write and where to place it).

I am new to Magento.

I am running Magento 2.0.

**I came up whit this solution. But please find me a better one!**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Get the form key</title>
<script>

window.onload=function(){

/* Get form_key from Magento */
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "/", false);
ajax.send();
document.getElementById('hidden_div').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
var the_form_key = document.getElementsByName("form_key")[0].value;

alert(the_form_key);

};

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the API instead?

Comment: That might be better! But the documentation on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html is to difficult for me. I just know basic PHP and Javascript. Any suggestions of easy tutorials?

Answer (score 8):

For `frontend` area use the `jQuery.cookie` plugin which is a part of Magento 2:

`var $formKey = jQuery.cookie('form_key');`

For `adminhtml` area use `FORM_KEY` JavaScript constant:

`var $formKey = FORM_KEY;`

Answer (score 6):

There is an example in:
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    ..
    'mage/cookies'
```

```
'form_key': $.mage.cookies.get('form_key')
```

I see in admin (backend namespace) that there are many calls to `window.FORM_KEY`